# creating intents dynamically with putExtra for a ListView?

Tags: android, android-intent

I made an design wich "feels" wrong. So maybe you can tell me how to better, or if my solution isn't that bad.

The model is:

I've database Tables for my menu structure in my app. For main menu, sub menus etc. The database tables are look like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE `main_menu` (
    `_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `name`  TEXT,
    `sortIndex` INTEGER,
    `intent`    TEXT
);
```

then in the code I query the database and put all the column info into a class like this:

```
public class MainMenu {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int sortIndex;
    private String intent;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSortIndex() {
        return sortIndex;
    }

    public void setSortIndex(int sortIndex) {
        this.sortIndex = sortIndex;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getIntent() {
        return intent;
    }

    public void setIntent(String intent) {
        this.intent = intent;
    }
}
```

In the next step the menu is used like this:

```
mainMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "ListItem clicked id:"
                + id);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        switch ((int)id) {
            case 0:
                intent.setAction(values.get(0).getIntent());
                break;
            case 1:
                intent.setAction(values.get(1).getIntent());
                break;
            case 2:
                intent.setAction(values.get(2).getIntent());
                break;
            case 3:
                intent.setAction(values.get(3).getIntent());
                break;
            case 4:
                intent.setAction(values.get(4).getIntent());
                break;
            case 5:
                intent.setAction(values.get(5).getIntent());
                break;
            case 6:
                intent.setAction(values.get(6).getIntent());
                break;
        }

        try{
            startActivity(intent);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

The advantage of this construct is, that i can change the sort order of the menu items as i wish, but i can't putExtras to them. In my case two menu items are starting the same activity but with different flags. So I made an detour. I call another Activity an start the "real" Activity from there with the correct flag.

So this feels not good at all, but it's the only way my knowledge made me do it. Apart from the fact that the number of entries have to be hardcoded in the

```
switch(){
case:
}
```

block, wich isn't quite that what I intended when I decided to put all the info into a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using row id for getting action from `values` ArrayList so no need to use `switch-case`. just pass `id` to get clicked item Action from ArrayList:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(values.get((int)id).getIntent());
startActivity(intent);
```

**Note:**

Your logic is not clear why you are using `id` to get clicked row data from `values` ArrayList because `id` is `long` id for ListView row. instead of position of row which is clicked.

*Probably you should use position instead of `id` for get action from ArrayList*

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
MainMenu clickedObject = (MainMenu)adapter.getItem(position);
intent.setAction(clickedObject.getIntent());
startActivity(intent);
```

Make sure you are overriding `getItem` in Adapter and returning `values.get(position)` from it.

Comment: your solution simplifies it a lot, thanks for that. Sometimes you're blinded by the lights...